# How to apply classes on array of objects from another array based on id

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hi I have a array of objects containing users with property uid and
name and, I have one more array of objects this array contains uid
and className. Now I want to apply these classes on users based on
uid and if the uid is not present in classesArray then offline class should apply to all those users *and these arrays are not sorted*

```js
userArray = [
  { uid: 11, uname: "nana" },
  { uid: 12, uname: "jack" },
  { uid: 17, uname: "wazir" },
  { uid: 15, uname: "cobra" },
  { uid: 16, uname: "janes" },
  { uid: 14, uname: "furan" },
  { uid: 13, uname: "arvind" },
];

classesArray = [
  { uid: 11, class: "online" },
  { uid: 14, class: "busy" },
  { uid: 13, class: "offline" },
  { uid: 12, class: "online" },
];
```

*and i want the array like this:*

```js
MergedArray = [
  { uid: 11, unane: "nana", class: "online" },
  { uid: 12, unane: "jack", class: "online" },
  { uid: 13, unane: "arvind", class: "offline" },
  { uid: 14, uname: "furan", class: "busy" },
  { uid: 15, uname: "cobra", class: "offline" },
  { uid: 16, uname: "janes", class: "offline" },
  { uid: 17, uname: "wazir", class: "offline" },
];
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should add the code you've attempted to your question. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` and `find` like this:

```
const mergeArray = userArray.map((userItem) => {
  classesItem = classesArray.find((item) => item.uid === userItem.uid);
  return classesItem ? { ...userItem, class: classesItem.class } : {...userItem, class: "offline" };
});
```